# Textbook(s) on epistemology

Tags: epistemology, truth, phenomenology

I was following a course on Merleau-Ponty​ and realised from the first few readings that I knew too little about theories of truth to truly appreciate what I was reading. Are there any books I could follow to obtain a better grasp of the topic.

Comment: You can also use [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html).

Comment: Specifically on epistemology: Paul Moser (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of Epistemology](https://books.google.it/books?id=SSNR_XDo8WoC&printsec=frontcover9).

Comment: On phenom. Dan Zahavi  (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of Contemporary Phenomenology](https://books.google.it/books?id=e_FXrgEACAAJ).

Comment: On Merleau-Ponty, you can see Taylor Carman, [Merleau-Ponty](https://books.google.it/books?id=1f7K23eDiOMC&printsec=frontcover) (2008) as well as Taylor Carman (editor), [The Cambridge Companion to Merleau-Ponty](https://books.google.it/books?id=skuiWiWHaxEC&printsec=frontcover) (2005).